# How to detect whether the app is running on WE8H or normal Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, barcode

I'm developing an app that can run on Windows Embeddded 8.1 Handheld and also on normal Windows Phone 8.1. On WE8H I want to use the new in-built BarcodeScanner type which works fine but not so on a consumer Windows Phone. I cannot find any differences in the environment properties and the information on the OS version.

If I understand it right, WE8H is just a plain WP8 with additional assemblies and administration possibilities. On the development site there I don't see any differences, I can use BarcodeScanner in my WP8 project, I just get a crash in the WP8-Emulator on creating an instance of a custom type using BarcodeScanner. So my idea is to test the BarcodeScanner type on existence by loading the type by the full qualified name and if it is not there then just ignore my own custom types that are using BarcodeScanner and the whole PointOfService namespace. Following actually works:

`var barcodeType = Type.GetType("Windows.Devices.PointOfService.BarcodeScanner, Windows.Devices.PointOfService, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime", false);`

My question is whether I can rely on such a test or not in the future. Or do you know a better solution to get the running OS?

Thanks in advance!
Waldemar

Comment: Interesting problem. What are the values of the `environment properties` and `OS version`?

Comment: On WE8.1H:

System.Environment.OSVersion
{Microsoft Windows NT 8.10.12359.0}
    Platform: Win32NT
    Version: {8.10.12359.0}

On WP8.1:
{Microsoft Windows NT 8.10.12358.0}
    Platform: Win32NT
    Version: {8.10.12358.0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waldemar, sorry for the delay. I forwarded your question to a Microsoft technical Evangelist. He replied that the difference is not easy to detect.

From his point of view, the better way is to try to do Reflection on a WEH object not supported by WP (and catch the exception). But he hasn't tested it.

So your initial idea seems to be quite good also.

Comment: Thank you very much! With this in my mind I can keep testing the Barcode type :)